# Is it possible to differentiate a black box model in Python?

Tags: python, autograd

Is it possible to find the gradient of a black box model? For instance, given the following trained random forest model

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# define dataset
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=5, n_informative=3, noise=0.1, random_state=2)

model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X, y)
```

I would like to find the derivatives with respect to all the variables of this function

```
def fun(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5):
    a = model.predict([[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]])[0]
    return(a)
```

I was wandering if it possible to do with (for instance) autograd something similar to

```
from autograd import grad, jacobian

grad(fun, 0)(-0.89,-1.06,-0.25,-0.53,0.21)
```

Comment: It might *run*, but probably Random Forest derivative would be very numerically unstable. In the vicinity of `[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]` point you'll either get the same answer (if it ends up in the same branch, thus having derivative 0), or a *sharply* different answer (if it's another branch, the derivative is infinite)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So what would you suggest to do? A non-tree based model (e.g., a neural network)? And, still, what would be the code for getting derivatives of a black box model?

Comment: You can't expect to get derivatives of any black box. The neural networks is a good idea, because the frameworks with them already use autograd behind the scenes to decompose complex neural architectures into separate differentiable steps.

Comment: You might also look for [JAX library](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/quickstart.html), they also provide many differentiable operations